# Post values to controller from table rows that are created dynamically

Tags: codeigniter

I am using codeigniter for a project.

I have a table with rows added dynamically through jquery append.

So when I click on a button submit, it post values for all the rows values to the controller, but I am not sure how to do that.

My table row is like this

```
<td>
  <input type="text" class="createWOBlockBG large ui-autocomplete-input" name="basefabrics" id="basefabrics1" autocomplete="off"> 
</td>
```

I do not want to use ajax calls.. How do I pass many of the inputs from the view to the controller?Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If your `table with rows` and as mentioned submit button is inside a form
then specify `action` attribute of your form to the controller where you want to access your values

and in the controller you can get the values as follows

```
$value = $this->input->post('name_of_your_input');
```

considering your input

```
$base_fabrics = $this->input->post('basefabrics');
```

if your form action is calling the same controller method which loaded the view, you can check for the click of submit button and then fetch values

```
if ($this->input->post('name_of_submit_btn'))
{
    $base_fabrics = $this->input->post('basefabrics');
}
```

**EDIT**: if all your inputs have same name then better name it as `name="basefabrics[]"`
so that when you fetch the value

```
$base_fabrics = $this->input->post('basefabrics');
```

`$base_fabrics` will be an array

Comment: for example if I have many input elements with the same name basefabrics, so my $base_fabrics will be an array of values?